# Subscribe to event eventhandler delegate from method without parameters

Tags: c#, subscriptions, eventhandler

I wanna make subscribtion to the `Close` event with the method `ClearControl`. The signature is different, but I don't need arguments from event. Is it possible ?

`public event EventHandler Close = delegate { }`;

```
public void ClearControl(){}

control1.Close += control2.ClearControl;
```

Comment: you can do this. `control1.Close += (s,e) => {ClearControl();}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method signature has to match with event signature.

if you don't want to use `Arguments` that's just fine, very normal case.

You can do this to call `ClearControl` method when `Close` is being called.

```
control1.Close += (s,e) => { ClearControl(); }
```

Comment: True, I just follow that convention in my coding ;)